# Documentation about writing a CoreCLR host in c++

Tags: c#, c++, coreclr

I'm writing a CoreCLR host in c++.

I'have succesfully called a c# function from a c++:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting

Reading that documentation:

> Another option, if ExecuteAssembly doesn't meet your host's needs, is
>   to use CreateDelegate to create a function pointer to a static managed
>   method. This requires the host to know the signature of the method it
>   is calling into (in order to create the function pointer type) but
>   allows hosts the flexibility to invoke code other than an assembly's
>   entry point.

given a c# function how can I "create the c++ function pointer type"

for example, for a function like this:

```
public static int withParams(int aNumber, string[] args)
```

are there some marshaling/unmarshaling rules, how do I behave with objects or arrays as parameters?

Is there a decent ufficial documentation for embedding coreclr in c++ code?

I look for something like this (but for coreclr):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation contains the code you need.

```
void *pfnDelegate = NULL;
hr = runtimeHost->CreateDelegate(
  domainId,
  L"HW, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral",  // Target managed assembly
  L"ConsoleApplication.Program",            // Target managed type
  L"Main",                                  // Target entry point (static method)
  (INT_PTR*)&pfnDelegate);

((MainMethodFp*)pfnDelegate)(NULL);
```

I created a class in a dotnet core dll and able to call it from cpp as follows.

```
void *pfnDelegate = NULL;
hr = runtimeHost->CreateDelegate(
    domainId,
    L"SampleAppCore",  // Target managed assembly
    L"SampleAppCore.Start", // Target managed type
    L"Run",                 // Target entry point (static method)
    (INT_PTR*)&pfnDelegate);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("ERROR - Failed to execute %s.\nError code:%x\n", targetApp, hr);
    return -1;
}


char* hello = "hello ";

((MainMethodFp*)pfnDelegate)(hello);
```

*Format of the delegate*

```
typedef void (STDMETHODCALLTYPE MainMethodFp)(char* args);
```

*Core Class*

```
using System;
namespace SampleAppCore
{

    public static class Start{

        public static void Run(string input){

            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: BSTR for a string, SAFEARRAY* for a string[].

Comment: This sample uses char*, why @HansPassant says BSTR? Is there some docs about it or I must reverse engineering the samples in order to understand?